# How to correct add iframe in ruby on rails app by using form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Make my frist RoR app, i want to make a form to insert ifrme

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?layer=c&amp;panoid=4L2HRkzKhDkAAAQJOOolAg&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;source=embed&amp;output=svembed&amp;cbp=13%2C125.96039999999999%2C%2C0%2C0"></iframe><div><small><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/views/u/0/" style="color:#0000FF; text-align:left">Phototour</a>: <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/views/u/0/view/105063597672690553440/gphoto/5942493604463072898" style="color:#0000FF; text-align:left">Valle Chajnantor 5000 msnm, II region, Chile</a>, <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/views/u/0/profile/105063597672690553440" style="color:#0000FF; text-align:left">Edward Ormeño</a></small></div>
```

buy how shoud i do this correctly in this template?  This is view template.

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @panorama.title %>
</p>

<h1>Panorama</h1>
  <%= sanitize (@panorama.code) %>


<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= @panorama.description %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_panorama_path(@panorama) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', panoramas_path %>
```

My form template here i need to code area insert iframe into this part

```
<%= sanitize (@panorama.code) %>
```

```html
<%= form_for(@panorama) do |f| %>
  <% if @panorama.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@panorama.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this panorama from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @panorama.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :code %><br>
    <%=  f.text_area :code %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you explain some more about what you want to do?  You say "make a form to insert ifrme" (i assume you mean iframe) but this doesn't really explain what you want to do.  Eg, insert into what?  Which form?  etc

Comment: I whant to insert 360photos form google site
https://www.google.com/maps/views/view/104480032847444434150/gphoto/6117437897870305490?hl=ru&gl=us&heading=330&pitch=90&fovy=75
Using this form, but iframe code doesn't insert corectly

Comment: It's not clear which form you are referring to there.  Do you mean there is a form which gives you some html to paste into your page to embed the map, and when you add that embed html to your page it isn't working properly?

Comment: Yes, i use sanitize method, but this not working.
How corect paste ? Which method should i use.
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Can you add, to your question, the value of `@panorama.code` please.

Comment: value is equal to < %= f.text_area :code %>
I want to insert iframe(code at the top of the topic).

Comment: By "value" i mean "what do you get as a result of calling "@panorama.code".  Eg if i say "@x = 1 + 1" and then ask "what is the value of @x?" you would say "2".  It's a variable.  What is the value held in the variable?